# How to retrieve 20,000 documents from firestore database using javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am having a firestore database, where it having a collection named emails. In emails it is having thousands of documents with dynamically created DocumentId's but i need to retrieve the data from each & every document.

tried syntax :- db.collection("emails").get().then((snapshot) => {});

example:-

emails -  001H2rmjHGOE4joI9kZQ58e9ET93 - name,age,phoneNumber
00L9cjByEHPmzJpBfhSvuRaiKk42- name,age,phoneNumber
i need all the phoneNumbers from every document by using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

a simple thing, create a bucket in your firebase console, next create a dataset and download the required data using SQL type console it provides JSON, CSV file formats follow below link for the full process.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3J1M1bSwgV8&list=LL&index=14&t=3s